# 'standard' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to integrate some kind of code linting for node.js in webstorm so I installed [standard](https://standardjs.com/) to my node.js project using:

```
npm instal standard --save-dev
```

It was installed and listed in the "devDependencies" section of package.json but when I run the command:

```
standard
```

in the console I get

```
'standard' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: Install it globally if you want to use it globally. PS. This "standard" is neither standard, nor is it advisable to use. I'd definitely find another styleguide to follow, that defines best practices such as using semicolons.

Comment: It seems there is a [native support](https://standardjs.com/#webstorm-phpstorm-intellij-rubymine-jetbrains-etc) for _standard_ in webstorm.

Comment: my whole node and npm installation was doomed, just reinstalled everything and worked fine

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use it locally you have to include it in you scripts first in package.json

  `"scripts": {
     "standard": "standard",
    "standard::fix": "standard --fix"
  }`

and use `npm  run standard` to run it. or if you are using yarn type `yarn standard`

Answer (score 1):

The scripts are in `node_modules\.bin`.

So, either:

1. Add this to `PATH` before running `standard`, e.g.:

   ```
   set PATH=%PATH%;node_modules\.bin
   ```
2. Run it in using `node_modules\.bin\standard`
3. Use @tarek's approach using `package.json`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49026837/122441

Answer (score 0):

```
 "scripts": {

    "test": "standard middlewares/validations.js"
  }
```

1. Add above lines in package.json.
2. Here middlewares/validations.js is the path of the file to check.
3. Run -> npm test
4. If this file have any error you will get.